# Datetime in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

How to i convert "04/16/2012 03:44:26" string to datetime object in ruby?

I knew that "20120416" can be converted to datetime object by DateTime.parse(srting).

Please some one help me in converting "04/16/2012 03:44:26" to datetime object in ruby. And  i need to add x minute to the above datetime object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the format using DateTime#strptime:

```
DateTime.strptime("04/16/2012 03:44:26", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

See: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime

You can add x minutes like so: `+ (x / (24 * 60.0))`.

If you are using Rails or have no problems using ActiveSupport, you can just do:

```
require 'active_support'
new_datetime = datetime + 10.minutes
```

Comment: tats fine.. its working.. how can i add x minutes to the date time object in ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: You can add x minutes like so: `+ (x / (24 * 60.0))`. However, this is pure Ruby style and you should use ActiveSupport for this.

Comment: Thanks.. i am using ruby for some auto testing.. so inorder to validate some thinf i need the date time conversion. Since i am not using ruby for development i did not like to use ActiveSupport here.. thanks for your help.. it provides more information unknown to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
(Time.parse("04/16/2012 03:44:26") + 10.minutes).to_datetime
```

**UPDATE**

Works even in Ruby 1.8.7, but you need to require ActiveSupport (used automatically in Rails).

Comment: sorry.. it does not work.. i am using ruby 1.8.7. forgot to mention this in question. Your code throws "NoMethodError: undefined method `minutes' for 10:Fixnum" in ruby 1.8.7. Thank you. IT will be greatfull if there is any solution for ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Try replacing `10.minutes` with `600`.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention ActiveSupport. Fixed.

Comment: thanks lukas for your support.. i was able to fix thiss issue.. i am not using rails framework.. mostly ruby script was used for auto testing along with selenium. Anyways your answers will be useful for me in development using rails framework.